# save all associated records at once

Tags: php, cakephp

I am able to save associated records in cakephp3 but if you look at the code , the records are not saved all at once with 1 save call.
I did have a problem trying to save all the records at once. If you look at how its done you see the Guardian and Users table are save separately.
The code works and saves the records but saving all at once in 1 save call has been an issue as I got an error on the guardian table.

```
Guardians have a 1 to many relationship with students
Students and Users have a 1 to 1 
Students to subjects and availabilityFotStudents both have a many to many
```

Code

```
   public function add($gId=0) {
        $this->loadModel("Guardians");
        $this->loadModel('PaymentTypes');
        $this->set("title","Add Student");
        $guardians=null;


        if ($gId>0){
            $guardians =$this->Guardians->get($gId);
        }

        if ($this->request->is('post')) {

            if ( $this->request->data['studenttype']==0){ //enquiry
                $this->request->data['students']['address_billing'] = 0;
                 $this->request->data['students']['student_enq'] = 1;
            }
            else   if ( $this->request->data['studenttype']==1){ //waitlist
                $this->request->data['students']['address_billing'] = 1;
                 $this->request->data['students']['student_enq'] = 0;
            }
            else if ( $this->request->data['studenttype']==2){ //skip waitlist
                $this->request->data['students']['address_billing'] = 4;
                 $this->request->data['students']['student_enq'] = 0;
            }            

            if ( $this->request->data['students']['tutoring_typest_id']==1){
                $this->request->data['students']['group_status']=0;
            }
            else if ( $this->request->data['students']['tutoring_typest_id']>1){
                $this->request->data['students']['group_status']=1;
            }

            if ($this->request->data['students']['tutoring_typest_id']==3 ){//group only
                $this->request->data['students']['address_billing'] = 4;
            }

            $data = $this->request->data;
           // debug($data);



              $uname=  $this->request->data['Users']['username'];
              if ($this->Students->Users->findByUsername($uname)->count())  {
                $this->Flash->error(__('Username exists. Please, try again.'));
                return $this->redirect(["action"=>"add",$gId]);
               }
              $userId=0;

              $entity = $this->Students->Users->newEntity($this->request->data['Users'],['validate'=>false]);
              $entity->role = "student";
             $entity['role_id'] =  4;
              $entity = $this->Students->Users->save($entity);

          //  debug( $entity);
              $studentUserId =  $entity->id;


            if($guardians==null) {
                $guardians = $this->Guardians->newEntity($this->request->data['guardians'], ['validate' => false]);
            }

            $guardianEntity = $this->Guardians->save($guardians);
            $guardians = $this->Students->newEntity();
            $studentData = $this->request->data['students'];
            $studentData['subjects'] = $this->request->data['subjects'];
            $studentData['availability_for_students'] = $this->request->data['availability_for_students'];
            $studentEntity = $this->Students->patchEntity($guardians,$studentData,
                [
                    "validate"=>false,
                    'associated' => [
                        "AvailabilityForStudents"=>["validate"=>false],
                        "Subjects"=>["validate"=>false]
                    ]

                ]
            );
            $studentEntity->guardian_id = $guardianEntity->id;
            $studentEntity->user_id = $studentUserId;

            $studentEntity = $this->Students->save($studentEntity,
                [
                    "validate"=>false,
                    'associated' => [
                        "AvailabilityForStudents"=>["validate"=>false],
                        "Subjects"=>["validate"=>false]
                    ]

                ]
            );
            if ($studentEntity) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The student has been saved'));
                return $this->redirect(["action"=>"index2"]);
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error(__('The student could not be saved. Please, try again.'),'flash_alert');
            }

        }//post
        $subjects = $this->Students->Subjects->find('list', array( 'order' => array('Subjects.name' => 'asc') ));
        $weekdays = $this->Students->weekDays;
        $tutoringTypes = $this->Students->TutoringTypeStudents->find('list');


        //$payments = $this->Student->paymentOptions;
        $this->PaymentTypes->primaryKey("name");
        $payments  = $this->PaymentTypes->find( 'list', array(
            'fields'     => array('PaymentTypes.name','PaymentTypes.name'))  );
        $referrals = $this->Students->Referrals->find('list');
        $tutorGender = $this->Students->Lessons->Tutors->tutorGender;

        $this->set('guardians', $guardians);
        $this->set(compact('referrals','subjects', 'tutoringTypes', 'weekdays','payments','tutorGender'));

    }
```

Comment: I still cant get this to work so if anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [Tranactional](http://api.cakephp.org/3.1/class-Cake.Database.Connection.html#_transactional) data save. Where you can run multiple save method. if any save method failed then no data will be save. so it works like  "1 save call" which you mentioned